# ORACLE/SYBASE SQL Clarification

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

Data length is random in a specific field as below:

I want to select only the characters before to the special character.

Samples:

```
123456_3
454656484784_13
15051514745_7
```

Expected result is as below:

```
123456
454656484784
15051514745
```

Answer (score 0):

General example:

`substring(your_data, 0, instr(your_data, '_'))`

Answer (score 0):

To get the 1st part

```
select substr(your_column, 1, INSTR(your_column, '_') - 1) 
from your_table
```

To get the last part

```
select substr(your_column, INSTR(your_column, '_') + 1) 
from your_table
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/5736)

Comment: @uergen d : this one helped me. but how can i modify the same to retrive the characters after _ symbol         eg : 12123454_aa -> aa in this case                                                                           1545454_a -> only a in this case

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty - you can figure out how to do this in a single step as Oracle/Sybase procedure or such...

```
-- Ignore 0 or negative numbers --
-- This gives you your end pos for substr --
SELECT distinct(Instr('123456_3 454656484784_13 15051514745_7', '_', LEVEL)-1) substr_end_pos
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < length('123456_3 454656484784_13 15051514745_7') 
  /

 -- This is start pos for substr --
 SELECT Distinct(Instr('123456_3 454656484784_13 15051514745_7', ' ', LEVEL)+1)  substr_start_pos
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL < length('123456_3 454656484784_13 15051514745_7')
  /

 -- These are substr start/end numbers returned by above queries --
 Select Substr('123456_3 454656484784_13 15051514745_7',  1, 6) From dual -- substr_start_pos=1, substr_end_pos=6
 /

 Select Substr('123456_3 454656484784_13 15051514745_7',  10, 21-9) From dual -- substr_start_pos=10, substr_end_pos=21-substr_start_pos-1
 /

 Select Substr('123456_3 454656484784_13 15051514745_7',  26, 36-25) From dual -- substr_start_pos=26 substr_end_pos=36-substr_start_pos-1
/
```